# after using \def I cannot use math formula

Tags: math-mode, errors

This is what I type in:

```
exist
    f(x) - f(a) = \(frac{f(x) - f(a)}{(x - a)}\)
  \def\lim {$lim_{x \to a}$}
    \lim[f(x) - f(a)] = \lim $frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$(x-a)
    \\* = \lim $frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$ X \lim (x - a)
    \\* = f'(a) $bullet$ 0 = 0
```

After I use `\def` I can't use math formula any more, such as `$frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$`
Should I change anything??
Thanks

Comment: There are many syntactic errors in the code snippet. What are you trying to display?

Comment: I want to use "\def" to create "\lim" which means "$lim_{x \to a}$" and comes with math formula such as $frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$

Comment: You seem to be encountering too many errors. While I like the approach of learn while using, still you can not ignore having some basic foundations. This is going to be eventually beneficial (and time saving) if you go through some introductory material like [LSHORT](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/). Spend a dedicated and intense weekend on this one, and you will be ready to venture out. Please type the examples yourself, do not copy and paste. I can not tell you how important this is. Taking a look at some good book helps. Please check which are stocked by your library.

Answer (score 8):

`\lim` is an already existing command; why do you try to (re)define it using `\def`?

Perhaps this is what you are trying to achieve?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

since \( f(x) - f(a) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}\), we have  
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to a}[f(x) - f(a)] &= \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}(x-a) \\ 
&= \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} \times \lim_{x \to a} (x - a) \\ 
& = f'(a) \cdot 0 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since your code snippet has so many syntactic problems, I would suggest you to read some basic introductory material; [`lshort`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort), perhaps and [`mathmode`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathmode) and the documentation of the [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

Perhaps the intent on using \def was to define a new command to facilitate the typesetting of limits; is this was the case, then you can do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\mylim[2][x]{\lim_{#1\to #2}}

\begin{document}

\[
\mylim{a}x=a\quad \mylim{b}x^{2}=b^{2}\quad \mylim[y]{c}k=k.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\newcommand` and not `\def` since the former checks is the command was already defined to avoid overwriting a possible previous definition. In general, always use `\newcommand` instead of `\def` (unless you know what yu are doing).

Comment: That is it!!!Thank you so much. You really help me a lot. I don't know how to express my appreciate:D I'm trying to use latex to organize my note, however, it cost me five times more than organize by my hand.:(

Comment: is it possible for me to use "\def" ?

Comment: @HuangElizabeth `\def` is a command used to define macros; normally, only if you know what you are doing you should use it. In your concrete case there's no need to use it; in fact, the way you were using is completely wrong. What do you want to use `\def` for?

Comment: @HuangElizabeth I updated my answer providing the definition of a command to typeset limits. Is it something like that what you were trying to achieve with `\def`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to use. Thank you:D